# C# SHA256 Hash XML File & Verfiy Hash in PHP

Tags: c#, php, hash

I'm currently using C# to hash an generated XML File to maintain XML File Intergiry with a server issued salt. However, when checking the hash of the XML File with PHP, the hash output on PHP does not match with the hash output on C#.

C# Code

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(this.XMLFile);
            document.Element("workorder").Add(
                new XElement("submit",
                    new XElement("comments", this.comments.Text),
                )
            );
            string xml = document.ToString();
            document.Save(this.XMLFile);


StringBuilder sha256_Sb = new StringBuilder();
var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SERVERHASH-SHA256"));
hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(document.ToString()));
foreach(byte hash256 in hmacsha256.Hash)
{
    sha256_Sb.Append(hash256.ToString("x2"));
}

MessageBox.Show(sha256_Sb.ToString());
```

C# Hash Output

`8b969aef8b91b6c9cfed6f9b54b562ba89fc6d0b4d817868a88910c043027815`

PHP Code - Checking XML File Intergiry

```
$xml = file_get_contents('../files/workorders/y50onuv1_1702700056.xml');
$hash = hash_hmac("SHA256", mb_convert_encoding($xml, "UTF-8") , mb_convert_encoding("SERVERHASH-SHA256", "UTF-8"));
echo $hash;
```

PHP Hash Output

`986fbb2028854ebbf31f28338876a0d8364ac3c73530404f813968ce5667da8a`

I tried other exampes in searching other examples, prevoisuly, I had an encoding issue where I had C# was outputting ASCII, but I tried using UTF-8. It still didn't match the hash. I'm not sure where I'm missing the issue trying to get the hash to match with C# and PHP.

Any assistance or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's sha512_Sb?

Comment: @shingo - local variable to StringBuilder Instance

Comment: There's only one local variable to StringBuilder instance in the question, but its name is sha**256**_Sb.

Comment: Corrected, my mistake, it should be sha256_Sb. But still same output

Comment: You should compare the value between `document.ToString()` and `$xml`. You should use `File.ReadAllBytes` in C# because xml APIs could format the document. Pay attention to spaces, line breaks, etc.

Comment: Get rid of `mb_convert_encoding()`. Why are you calling it in the first place?